# Handling bad data with an java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date error

Tags: scala, date

There are several other discussions around `ParseExceptions`, but they seem to generally involve tweaking locales, time zones, or the input string.

We have the following code:

```
  val ISO8601 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")

  val getCrawlDate: String = {
    if (r.t.getFormat == ArchiveFormat.ARC) {
      ExtractDate(arcRecord.getMetaData.getDate, DateComponent.YYYYMMDD)
    } else {
      ExtractDate(ArchiveUtils.get14DigitDate(ISO8601.parse(warcRecord.getHeader.getDate)), DateComponent.YYYYMMDD)
    }
}
```

In the former case it is looking for something like `20080430204825` and in the latter case something like `2008-04-30T20:48:25Z`.

But what happens if we cannot control our data, and instead of the above 14-digit strings, a string like `200012060402` (12-digits) is passed.

Right now we get some variation of

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "200012060402"
```

Is there any efficient way to handle bad junk data?

Comment: Even though you are getting a Java exception, your question isn't really about [tag:java], but rather about [tag:scala].  Please be more mindful of tags going forward.

Comment: What's wrong with catching the exception and trying to recover using the alternative date format?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Using `try` & `catch`?

Answer (score 0):

What if you just add extra zeroes to make the date "valid"?
For example:

```
val date = "200012060402"

val parsedDate = if(date.length < 14)
  date + ( "0" * (14 - date.length))
else date
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply try a bunch of different formats?

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

val possibleFormats = List(
  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"),
  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH:mm"),
  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm")
)

def robustParse(s: String): Date = {
  for (f <- possibleFormats) {
      try {
          return f.parse(s)
      } catch {
        case e: ParseException => 
          // simply ignore it, try next pattern
      }
  }
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(
    "Could not parse " + s + " using any possible format"
  )
}

for (example <- List(
  "2000-01-01T01:00:00UTC",
  "2222-11-22T11:22:33",
  "200001021859"
)) {
  println(robustParse(example));
}
```

If you wanted to make it really robust, so that it can cope with all kind of weird date formats manually typed in by inaccurate people, then you would need something that looks more like "natural language" processing approach, even though the domain of discourse of the language is very narrow.

**Same in Java, just in case someone wants to have it...**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class HistoriansDateFormat {
    private static SimpleDateFormat[] possibleFormats = {
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"),
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH:mm"),
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm")
    };

    public static Date robustParse(String s) {
        for (SimpleDateFormat f: possibleFormats) {
            try {
                Date d = f.parse(s);
                return d;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // simply ignore it, try next pattern
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "Could not parse " + s + " using any possible format"
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String example: new String[]{
            "2000-01-01T01:00:00UTC",
            "2222-11-22T11:22:33",
            "200001021859"
        }) {
          System.out.println(robustParse(example));
        }
    }
}
```

(sorry, picked the wrong language initially)